# MySQL daily replication

Tags: mysql, replication

Replication every query in MySQL is spend some cost on database server.
Is it possible to log new query and replicate and run query on backup server once a day instead of replicate every query at every time?

If it possible, how?
Thanks.

Comment: it's not the same to do a daily mysqldump and copy/restore it to the backup server?

Comment: The server just writes the binlog and sends it to slaves. If your I/O is limited, put the binlog on a different disk than the data. If the slaves read the binlog continuously or in one batch once per day makes no difference in performance.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a cron job to [start and stop the replication](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replication-administration-pausing.html) with `STOP SLAVE;` and `START SLAVE;`

The problem is, the binlog will grow and the slave could spend a lot of time to catch up.

If the only purpose of the slave is to provide a backup solution you should consider using [InnoDB Hotbackup](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-backup.html).

Just to improve performance you should consider the suggestion of Erik Ekman and choose a different disk for binlog data.